# Kibana. Extract fields from @message containing a JSON

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, logstash-grok

I would like to extract in Kiabana fields from @message field which contains a json.
ex:

```
Audit{
uuid='xxx-xx-d3sd-fds3-f43',
action='/v1.0/execute/super/method', 
resultCode='SUCCESS', 
browser='null', 
ipAddress='192.168.2.44', 
application='application1', 
timeTaken='167'
}
```

Having "action" and "application" fields I hope to be able to find top 5 requests that hits the application.

I started with something similar to this:

```
filter {
    if ([message]~ = "Audit") {
        grok {
            match => {
                "message" => "%{WORD:uuid}, %{WORD:action}, %{WORD:resultCode}, %{WORD:browser}, %{WORD:ipAddress}, %{WORD:application}, %{NUMBER:timeTaken}"
            }
            add_field => ["action", "%{action}"]
            add_field => ["application", "%{application}"]
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems to be too far from reality.

Comment: can you show us entire log that you are trying to match?

Answer (score 1):

If the content of "Audit" is really in json format, you can use the filter plugin "json"

```
json{
    source => "Audit"
}
```

It will do the parsing for you and creates everything. You don't need grok / add_field.